# Handle screen touch events in Echo Show C#

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

The Display.ElementSelected event I get in my Alexa Skill,
how does the event get triggered? And how do Handle it in C#? Can you provide a working example.

I implemented an ElementSelected class in my project and I parse the request i receive from Alexa looking for it, but nothing returns. I don't think I'm doing this correctly. This is my class

```
namespace Alexa.NET.Request.Type
{
    public class ElementSelectedRequest : Request
    {
        private const string type = "Display.ElementSelected";

        protected ElementSelectedRequest()
        {
            this.Type = type;
        }

        [JsonProperty("token")]
        public string Token { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've seen all the java and javascript examples on github and I still don't understand how it works exactly.